# My scrollbar won't move the view down the page

Tags: python, tkinter

```
scrollcanvas=Canvas(window,bg="#ffffff",width=350,height=350)
scrollcanvas.configure(scrollregion=[0,0,400,400])
scrollcanvas.place(x=75,y=220)

syscroll=Scrollbar(scrollcanvas,orient=VERTICAL,width=20,command=scrollcanvas.yview,)
syscroll.place(anchor='ne',relx=1, rely=0, relheight=1)
```

I have tried adding bind but am still kind of new to python so unsure how this works.
The scrollbar displays correctly but just wont move the view down

Comment: new to stack overflow not sure about the formatting for questions

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How are you determining that the view won't move?  You've drawn nothing on the Canvas, so scrolling it has no visible effect.

Comment: You need to set `yscrollcommand=syscroll.set` on the canvas.

Comment: @jasonharper I have not included my full code so I know from my personal view that it doesn't work

Comment: @acw1668 thank you but where would I add it

Comment: Call `scrollcanvas.config(yscrollcommand=syscroll.set)` after creating the scrollbar.

Comment: @acw1668 hi its still not moving the view down the canvas

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre] as it is hard to identify the issue with just the incomplete posted code.

Comment: After creating a text and a triangle inside the canvas, I can see the scrolling using the scrollbar.  Of course I need to add stuff like creating `window` object and calling `mainloop()` to produce a [mre].